# WebView will not scroll on some devices without long touch

Tags: android, webview, scroll

I have a WebView set up as below:

```
    //the web view
    _mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

    //push the url on to the web view
    _mWebView.loadUrl(buildURL.toString());

    //make the view transparent to get rid of white box while loading
    _mWebView.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);

    //_mWebView.bringToFront();
    //_mWebView.requestFocus();
    //_mWebView.requestFocusFromTouch();
```

On some phones when the view has loaded it will scroll fine but on my device, Sensation Xe running 4.0.3, the view does not scroll. If I do a long touch on the view it selects some text and will then scroll normally. This is annoying as it will not be obvious to do this to the end user. I have tried a few things as outlined above, any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Scott, did you find a solution to this?

Comment: I have the same problem on Galaxy S3 Mini. Any solution?

Comment: I never resolved it sorry.

Answer (score 0):

add this line in your code, may be this help you try it,

```
_mWebView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. I have tried that and it didn't help :-(

Once the WebView has loaded it still will not scroll until I do a long touch on it and select some text.